# How to name worker?

Tags: phoenix-framework

I tired to use a `GenServer` as a worker:

```
defmodule CSVServer do
    use GenServer


    def start_link(_opts \\ []) do
        GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, %{}, name: __MODULE__)
    end


    def process!(csvs_params), do: GenServer.call(__MODULE__, %{csvs_params: csvs_params})

    def handle_call(%{csvs_params: csvs_params}, _from, state) do

    ...

    end
```

And at my app:

```
def start(_type, _args) do
    import Supervisor.Spec, warn: false

    children = [
      # Start the endpoint when the application starts
      supervisor(MyApp.Endpoint, []),

      # Start the Ecto repository
      supervisor(MyApp.Repo, []),

      worker(CSVServer, [], name: "CSVServer"),
    ]
```

The question is, do I have to explicitly name the worker? at:

```
worker(CSVServer, [], name: "CSVServer"),
```

isn't it already named at the `GenServer` as:

```
GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, %{}, name: __MODULE__)
```

?

**EDIT**

In the generated `myapp.ex` I can see this:

```
# Here you could define other workers and supervisors as children
# worker(MyApp.SomeWorker, [], name: SomeWorker),
```

Comment: Why are you adding `name` to the `options` argument of `worker`? I don't see any mention of a `name` key accepted by that argument in the docs. https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.Spec.html#worker/3

Comment: Kindly check edit above